# View object fields and data

Tags: fields, data, object

Is there a tool that allows you to view all the fields and the data in them on a record? I have a custom object with say 40 or 50 fields. I'd like to just view the record as you would if you browse a table in a regular database and see all the standard and custom fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about a quick select rather than typing all the fields, [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) is the best tool for me. You can navigate into query > soql query and from below view you can select all the fields easily and the results are shown in a usable manner.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also really like Workbench - it works great.

In addition to Workbench, you may also find [Enabler4Excel](https://www.enabler4excel.com/) very helpful. In addition to being able to see all the fields per object, and reporting that straight into Excel, this tool also has a huge number of other brilliant features. This [review](http://www.salesforceben.com/enabler4excel-reviewguide-tips/) on the tool may be useful to you.

You may also find these apps from the AppExchange interesting and helpful, to give you the fields per object. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI and https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ both have good reviews, and will give you what you want in addition to having numerous other helpful functions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Tab (of that custom object), Select the view 'All' and click 'Go'.  Add more fields/columns as you want to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can **create custom tabs for custom object**.
Just go to **setup->serch for create tabs** and create new tab for custom object.
Then you can use that tab to see the information of records.